# Ajax Control Toolkit CalendarExtender not closing when form body clicked

Tags: ajax, calendar

I am trying to simply have the calendar close when a user clicks anywhere on the page. I have downloaded the most recent version of the toolkit and I can not get this functionality to work. I am not sure if I am missing a property but the functionality works as expected on the asp.net sample toolkit page.

Here is the code:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>


<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" /><img runat="server" alt="Calendar" id="imgCalFrom" align="absmiddle" border="0" height="16" src="/global/images/glo_btn_cal.gif" width="21"/>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtTest" PopupButtonID="imgCalFrom">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `<img .,. />`. Use `<input type="image" .../>` instead. Or you can use `<asp:ImageButton runat="Server" .../>`. This will fix your problem.

Comment: what is the difference between those two tags? why the functionality is changing by changing the tag to imagaButton?

Answer (score 2):

There is some issue in the Toolkit that keeps it from working with an asp:Image, but works as expected with an asp:ImageButton. It should close the picker if you click outside of it.

As a best practice we always use a calendar icon to pop up the picker instead of when the textbox is clicked. Some users prefer typing dates in and popping the picker up every time they click a textbox is unexpected and unwanted.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the PopupButtonID="imgCalFrom" from the extender. That should fix it. This PopupButtonID assigns a button callback. You have to click the image again or selecting a date in order to close the calendar.

Comment: Correct, but hen you loose the functionality of having a user click on the button to display the calendar. 
So the question is, how do I have a calendar icon associated with a textbox that when clicked displays the calendar but when any other part of the page is clicked, the calender is hidden again.

Comment: If you are using an <img> tag for the PopupButtonID, switch to using ImageButton instead as below

    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgCalFrom" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.jpg" />

Comment: Then you loose the functionality of having a button fire the event to show the calendar.